# Get count of object property based on condition

Tags: javascript

I have a array of objects like below:

```
[  
   {  
      "commentId":1485594783811,
      "topicId":"1485594764668",
      "comments":"hi2",
      "commentDate":"1/31/2017, 12:59:08 PM",
      "userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
      "username":"k****@gmail.com"
   },
   {  
      "commentId":1485866129370,
      "topicId":"1485853106269",
      "comments":"Hi",
      "commentDate":"1/31/2017, 6:05:29 PM",
      "userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
      "username":"kv****@gmail.com"
   },
   {  
      "commentId":1485939547285,
      "topicId":"1485853106269",
      "comments":"Hi",
      "commentDate":"2/1/2017, 3:18:34 PM",
      "userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
      "username":"ki*****9@gmail.com"
   },
   {  
      "commentId":1485947026195,
      "topicId":"1485945483238",
      "comments":"hi",
      "commentDate":"2/1/2017, 4:33:46 PM",
      "userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
      "username":"ki****9@gmail.com"
   }
]
```

All the objects contain a `topicId` and `comments`(can be empty/null) property. I want to know the count of all the comments based on `topicId` which is like a primary key.

So I get to know how many users have commented on each topic. I tried some thing like this:

```
var count = 0;
res.forEach(function(el, i){
    self.data.topicIdArr.push(el.topicId);
});

self.data.topicIdArr.forEach(function(el, i){
    if(res[i].topicId == el){
        self.data.topicIdArr.push(count++);
    }
});
```

But I don't think its the correct way.

How do I do this?

Comment: First please provide relevant data sample. Second, please share what have you tried. If you have not tried anything, *hint*: `Array.filter`

Comment: If you are not able to write anything with `Array#filter`, try underscore's countBy method.

Comment: please add the array in literal format.

Comment: @Rajesh I heard of array filter but I didn't knew I could apply it in this scenario

Comment: @kittu Instead of `.push`, just do `count++` and at the end push it once.

Comment: Need more info. What's the relation between commentID, topicID and comments? How do they link together? In your example, does the comment 'hi2' have the id in commentID? They're both strings, so what happens when multiple comments are made on a topic? DO we have to comapre topicID with the commentID in some way? Or are all these objects comments and do we basically need to count how many times a certain topicID appears in different objects?

Comment: If you have a short length of array you can use your way. Else create one time map of objects by Id and use it every time

Comment: This sounds, like a DB logic rather than a JS one, DB would always be a lot faster too, are you doing this all wrong?

Comment: @Val I didn't want to do this DB side as It has make a ajax call, pass through security and then JPA repository and then count from two tables. I guess javascript is better. What do you say?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an object for counting.

```js
var data = [{ commentId: 1485594783811, topicId: 1485594764668, comments: "hi2", commentDate: "1/31/2017, 12:59:08 PM", userImage: "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png", username: "k****@gmail.com" }, { commentId: 1485866129370, topicId: 1485853106269, comments: "Hi", commentDate: "1/31/2017, 6:05:29 PM", userImage: "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png", username: "kv****@gmail.com" }, { commentId: 1485939547285, topicId: 1485853106269, comments: "Hi", commentDate: "2/1/2017, 3:18:34 PM", userImage: "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png", username: "ki*****9@gmail.com" }, { commentId: 1485947026195, topicId: 1485945483238, comments: "hi", commentDate: "2/1/2017, 4:33:46 PM", userImage: "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png", username: "ki****9@gmail.com" }],
    count = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a.topicId] = (count[a.topicId] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Then you get the count in the object, like

```
{
   "1485594764668": 1,
   "1485853106269": 2,
   "1485945483238": 1
}
```

Comment: Whats happening inside `count[a.topicId] || 0` You are checking if `a.topicId` is null?

Comment: it tests for a falsy value, like `undefined`, and return `0`.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have other requirement on top of this. I should have asked it in same question. I thought I would figure out. I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982607/how-to-insert-values-into-object-based-on-some-id

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new object that will have the topic ID for the key and the number of comments for the value

```js
var myArray = [{
  "commentDate": "1/31/2017, 12:59:08 PM",
  "commentId": 1485594783811,
  "comments": "hi2",
  "topicId": "1485594764668",
  "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
  "username": "ki******99@gmail.com"
}, {
  "commentDate": "1/30/2017, 12:59:08 PM",
  "commentId": 1485594783812,
  "comments": "hello",
  "topicId": "1485594764669",
  "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
  "username": "ki******99@gmail.com"
}, {
  "commentDate": "1/29/2017, 12:59:08 PM",
  "commentId": 1485594783813,
  "comments": "Hi man !",
  "topicId": "1485594764668",
  "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
  "username": "ki******99@gmail.com"
}];

var result = {};

myArray.forEach(function(o){
  result[o.topicId] = result[o.topicId] || 0;
  result[o.topicId]++;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just trying to understand here. What does `|| 0` do  in `result[o.topicId] || 0`. I mean why `topicId or 0`?

Comment: You are checking if topicId is null?

Comment: @kittu [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706372/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-this-code-in-javascript) will help you understand.

Comment: @kittu `result[o.topicId] || 0` will get the current counter OR 0 if there is no current value

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer. Actually I have other requirement on top of this. I should have asked it in same question. Posted a new question. Please check once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982607/how-to-insert-values-into-object-based-on-some-id

Answer (score 1):

almost same as previous answers, but has less readability, but also might be a bit fast on large collections.

```
> a
[ { commentId: 1485594783811,
    topicId: '1485594764668',
    comments: 'hi2',
    commentDate: '1/31/2017, 12:59:08 PM',
    userImage: 'assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png',
    username: 'k****@gmail.com' },
  { commentId: 1485866129370,
    topicId: '1485853106269',
    comments: 'Hi',
    commentDate: '1/31/2017, 6:05:29 PM',
    userImage: 'assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png',
    username: 'kv****@gmail.com' },
  { commentId: 1485939547285,
    topicId: '1485853106269',
    comments: 'Hi',
    commentDate: '2/1/2017, 3:18:34 PM',
    userImage: 'assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png',
    username: 'ki*****9@gmail.com' },
  { commentId: 1485947026195,
    topicId: '1485945483238',
    comments: 'hi',
    commentDate: '2/1/2017, 4:33:46 PM',
    userImage: 'assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png',
    username: 'ki****9@gmail.com' } ]
> counts = {}
> for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
... counts[a[i].topicId] = counts.hasOwnProperty(a[i].topicId) ? counts[a[i].topicId]+1 : 1;
... }
1
> counts
{ '1485594764668': 1, '1485853106269': 2, '1485945483238': 1 }
>
```

a rough implementation of: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-45