# How to insert values into object based on some Id

Tags: javascript

I want to insert values in to object based on `id` inside that object.

First Object:

```
{
    "topics": [{
        "id": 131,
        "topicId": "1485853106269",
        "title": "Topic Title",
        "details": "topic details",
        "username": "ki****@gmail.com",
        "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
        "dayPosted": "1/31/2017, 5:16:53 PM"
    }, {
        "id": 132,
        "topicId": "1485863413654",
        "title": "Check",
        "details": "topic details",
        "username": "ki****@gmail.com",
        "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
        "dayPosted": "1/31/2017, 5:20:13 PM"
    }, {
        "id": 133,
        "topicId": "1485945328280",
        "title": "New Topic",
        "details": "Sample Topic",
        "username": "ki****@gmail.com",
        "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
        "dayPosted": "2/1/2017, 4:05:28 PM"
    }, {
        "id": 134,
        "topicId": "1485945483238",
        "title": "New Topic2",
        "details": "New Topic2",
        "username": "ki****@gmail.com",
        "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
        "dayPosted": "2/1/2017, 4:08:03 PM"
    }],
    "role": "ROLE_ADMIN"
}
```

Second Object:

```
{
   "1485594764668": 1,
   "1485853106269": 2,
   "1485945483238": 1
}
```

I want to insert values from second object into first object based on the matching property `"topicId": "1485853106269"`.

For example: The value of `"topicId": "1485853106269"` in first object matches with a key inside second object so result would be like below with added value `"count": 2`:

```
{
    "id": 131,
    "topicId": "1485853106269",
    "title": "Topic Title",
    "details": "topic details",
    "username": "ki****@gmail.com",
    "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
    "dayPosted": "1/31/2017, 5:16:53 PM",
    "count": 2 //ADDED here
}
```

Comment: well what did you tried? But theory is loop through your objects and your second object properties check if anything match and if it does, add the value ;). Here is how you can loop through object properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: For the second object, I could do `for(key in object)` and for the first object  `forEach` but unable to figure out how to mix both to get the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = {"topics":[{"id":131,"topicId":"1485853106269","title":"Topic Title","details":"topic details","username":"ki****@gmail.com","userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png","dayPosted":"1/31/2017, 5:16:53 PM"},{"id":132,"topicId":"1485863413654","title":"Check","details":"topic details","username":"ki****@gmail.com","userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png","dayPosted":"1/31/2017, 5:20:13 PM"},{"id":133,"topicId":"1485945328280","title":"New Topic","details":"Sample Topic","username":"ki****@gmail.com","userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png","dayPosted":"2/1/2017, 4:05:28 PM"},{"id":134,"topicId":"1485945483238","title":"New Topic2","details":"New Topic2","username":"ki****@gmail.com","userImage":"assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png","dayPosted":"2/1/2017, 4:08:03 PM"}],"role":"ROLE_ADMIN"};

var countObj = {
    "1485594764668": 1,
    "1485853106269": 2,
    "1485945483238": 1
};

obj.topics.forEach(function(o){
     var c = countObj[o.topicId];
     if(c !== undefined)
         o.count = c;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple each loop will do:

```
obj.topics.forEach(item => item.count = counts[item.topicId])
```

Comment: @Andreas you sure about that? I've written this same code many times.

Comment: @Andreas Whoops. I forgot to `return prev` - either way, OP already had the count object so it was unnecessary.

Comment: You should check if `counts[item.topicId]` exist first. This could assign `undefined` as `item.count`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I don't see that as explicitly necessary, personally.

Comment: TO: "_I want to insert values from second object into first object **based on the matching property**_" -> No match = no `counts`

Comment: @Andreas Just about to paste that hhhh.

Comment: Right, and undefined is roughly equivalent to no `count`. the undefined check is strictly unnecessary because any comparisons you will do will either be if(counts) or if(counts > 0) or something like that, to which undefined will evaluate to 0.

Comment: I am new to javascript and I still don't understand es6 syntax (`=>`). Thank you for the answer anyway. I will try to learn and understand the syntax

Comment: Checking properties against `undefined` is the right way to check if it exist or not. If in the context of this question, it's not necessary, OP could learn from it.